# Python unicode character in __str__

Tags: python, string, unicode

I'm trying to print cards using their suit unicode character and their values. I tried doing to following:

```
def __str__(self):
    return u'\u2660'.encode('utf-8')
```

like suggested in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307014/python-str-versus-unicode), but I keep getting errors saying `UnicodeEncodeError: ascii, ♠, 0, 1, ordinal not in range(128)`. What can I do to get those suit character to show up when I print a list of cards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where does that `UnicodeEncodeError` occur exactly? I can think about two possible issues here:

- The `UnicodeEncodeError` occurs in you `__unicode__` method.
- Your `__unicode__` method returns a byte string instead of a unicode object and that byte string contains non-ASCII characters.

Do you have a `__unicode__` method in your class?

I tried this on the Python console according to the actual data from your comment:

```
>>> u'\u2660'.encode('utf-8')
'\xe2\x99\xa0'
>>> print '\xe2\x99\xa0'
♠
```

It seems to work. Could you please try to print the same on your console? Maybe your console encoding is the problem.

Comment: Yes, it does, which simply return the value u'\u2660'.

Comment: Thanks for quoting some actual data here, it helps a lot. I've just changed my solution according to the actual data from your message. See above.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. It does work as expected in the console. However, when I simply do "return u'\u2660'.encode('utf-8')" from the __str__ function in my class, I still get the error.

Comment: The code you provided works, but only when I run it with python 2.6, not the one that textmate calls by default (2.5.1). Thanks for the help; I'll remember to post the python version next time.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you have encoded those "suit symbols" into a byte string, you'll need to make the unicode string back for it by mentioning the appropriate codec (for example, `thebytestr.decode('latin-1')` if latin-1 is how you encoded it!), before making the `utf-8` encoding of that unicode string.  Just `unicode(something)` uses the default encoding, which is ASCII and therefore totally ignorant of any "suit symbols"!-)

As I said back then (3 months ago), I'd go for implementing `__unicode__` instead of `__str__`, but that's just a minor issue of simplicity. The core point is, rather: if your byte string includes anything outside of the limited ASCII encoding, you must know what encoding your byte string uses, and decode it back into Unicode by explicitly using that codec!

Answer (score 0):

I ran the same code and got

```html
>>> u'\u2660'.encode('utf-8')
'\xe2\x99\xa0'
>>> print ('\xe2\x99\xa0')
â™
```