# Why do you need this method inside a Django model?

Tags: python, django, unicode

```
class mytable(models.Model):
    abc = ...
    xyz = ...
    def __unicode__(self):
```

Why is the `def  __unicode__` necessary?

Answer (score 5):

These resources do a far better job at explaining that I can:

[Django Docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode)
[Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__unicode__)
[`__str__` versus `__unicode__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307014/python-str-versus-unicode)

In short, you need to define `__unicode__` so Django can print some readable representation when you call an object. `__unicode__` is also the 'new' preferred way to return your character string.

Answer (score 2):

[`__unicode__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__unicode__) is a Python "magic method" that determines how your object looks when you want to display that object as a unicode string.  It's not Django-specific or anything, but any time you either call `str()` or `unicode()` or use string interpolation and pass that object in, it will call that method to determine what unicode string is returned.

For objects displayed in templates, this method will be called to determine what is displayed in the template because this is the method that Python uses to determine what an object looks like as a character string.

Answer (score 1):

so the admin can display its breadcrumbs, and you are able to put {{ myobject }} into a template to show the `__unicode__` of your object.

Comment: In the template, why do I need to show the __unicode__ of the object?

Comment: for example: `<a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ object }}</a>`
And it's "unicode" instead of "str" because django uses unicode everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, there is one very important reason why to define the `__unicode__` method: the Django shell.

Playing with the console is usually a very powerful tool while developing a Django application, because it allows inspection of your (and others) classes, as well as quick prototype ideas and solutions.
And, working in the shell, every time you do a `print a` where `a` is a model instance, you will thank a lot having a `__unicode__` method that allows to easily recognize what object are you working with.