# Python difference between print obj and print obj.__str__() [at least with Unicode?]

Tags: python, unicode

I was given to understand that calling `print obj` would call `obj.__str__()` which would in turn return a string to print to the console. Now I head a problem with Unicode where I could not print any non-ascii characters. I got the typical "ascii out of range" stuff.

While experimenting the following worked:

```
print obj.__str__()
print obj.__repr__()
```

With both functions doing exactly the same (`__str__()` just returns `self.__repr__()`). What did not work:

```
print obj
```

The problem occured only with using a character out of ascii range. The final solution was to to the following in `__str__()`:

```
return self.__repr__().encode(sys.stdout.encoding)
```

Now it works for all parts. My question now is: Where is the difference? Why does it work now? I get if nothing worked, why this works now. But why does only the top part work, not the bottom.

OS is Windows 7 x64 with a default Windows command prompt. Also the encoding is reported to be `cp850`. This is more of a general question to understand python. My problem is already solved, but I am not 100% happy, mostly because now calling `str(obj)` will yield a string that is not encoded in the way I wanted it.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
class Sample(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = u"üé"

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

obj = Sample()
print obj.__str__(), obj.__repr__(), obj
```

Remove the last `obj` and it works. Keep it and it crashes with

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: What Python version are you running?

Comment: Show a minimal example of obj's class with samples of the strings you print.

Comment: Were you maybe looking for `obj.__unicode__()`?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python version is 2.7.2, I added a sample class, and no, I am not looking for unicode, because as far as I am informed that gets called, when you call `unicode(obj)` print calls `str(obj)` (or it should). Also testing with output: `__unicode__()` gets never called unless you call either `unicode(obj)` or `obj.__unicode__()`

Comment: Aside: you probably shouldn't call `__functions__` from outside an object. Use `str(obj)` and `repr(obj)` instead.

Comment: @millimoose thanks, I will take that into consideration. These were just for testing purposes, but as stated in your answer: My problem was caused because I did call a magic function directly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that print does something like the following for an object `obj` it's meant to print:

1. Checks if the `obj` is a `unicode`. If so, encodes it to `sys.stdout.encoding` and prints.
2. Checks if the `obj` is a `str`. If so, prints it directly.
3. If `obj` is anything else, calls `str(obj)` and prints that.

Step 1. is why `print obj.__str__()` works in your case.

Now, what `str(obj)` does is:

1. Call `obj.__str__()`.
2. If the result is a `str`, return it
3. If the result is a `unicode`, encodes it to `"ascii"` and return that
4. Otherwise, something mostly useless.

Calling `obj.__str__()` directly skips steps 2-3, which is why you don't get the encoding failure.

The problem isn't caused by how `print` works, it's caused by how `str()` works. `str()` ignores `sys.stdout.encoding`. Since it doesn't know what you want to do with the resulting string, the default encoding it uses can be considered arbitrary; `ascii` is as good or bad a choice as any.

To prevent this bug, make sure you return a `str` from `__str__()` as the documentation tells you to do. A pattern you could use for Python 2.x might be:

```
class Foo():
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'whatever'
    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode(sys.stdout.encoding)
```

(If you're sure you don't need the `str()` representation for anything but printing to the console.)

Comment: Thank you that is the perfect explanation I was looking for. This surely explains my problem. Now what if I *do* want to have more than just console output. What would be a good solution? My approach was to define a second parameter like this: `__str__(self, encoding=sys.stdout.encoding)`. Does this seem like a good idea?

Comment: @user1461135 There isn't really a situation where you would pass extra parameters into `__str__()`, seeing as you're not meant to call it directly. I'd just use `unicode(obj).encode('yadda')` wherever you'd want to call `obj.__str__(encoding='yadda')`, it's less likely to surprise people.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you look at [the online documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__), `__str__` and `__repr__` have different purposes and should create different outputs. So calling `__repr__` from `__str__` is not the best solution.

Second, `print` will call `__str__` and will not expect to receive non-ascii characters, because, well, `print` cannot guess how to convert the non-ascii character.

Finally, in recent versions of Python 2.x, `__unicode__` is the preferred method of creating a string representation for an object. There is an interesting explanation in [Python **str** versus **unicode**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1307210/191191).

So, to try and really answer the question, you could do something like:

```
class Sample(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = u"\xfc\xe9"

    # No need to implement __repr__. Let Python create the object repr for you

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Technically, in really recent versions of Python (3.x), the distinction doesn't exist anymore.