# Python string object not callable

Tags: python, string

I am not able to understand why I am getting a Type Error for the following statement

```
log.debug('vec : %s blasted : %s\n' %(str(vec), str(bitBlasted)))

type(vec)  is unicode
bitBlasted is a list
```

I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: don't name your string variable ``str`` you're shadowing the built-in ``str``

Comment: One of your parameter did not implement __str__

Comment: @Pooya nope. there would be a different error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Shadowing the built-in

Either [as Collin said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11460162/296974), you could be shadowing the built-in `str`:

```
>>> str = some_variable_or_string #this is wrong
>>> str(123.0) #Or this will happen
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

One solution would be to change the variable name to `str_` or something. A better solution would be to avoid this kind of Hungarian naming system -- this isn't Java, use Python's [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) to its fullest and use a more descriptive name instead.

### Not defining a proper method

Another possibility is that the object may not have a proper `__str__` method or even one at all.

The way Python checks for the `str` method is:-

- the `__str__` method of the class
- the `__str__` method of its parent class
- the `__repr__` method of the class
- the `__repr__` method of its parent class
- and the final fallback: a string in form of `<module>.<classname> instance at <address>` where `<module>` is `self.__class__.__module__`, `<classname>` is `self.__class__.__name__` and `<address>` is `id(self)`

Even better than `__str__` would be to use the new `__unicode__` method (in Python 3.x, they're `__bytes__` and `__str__`. You could then implement `__str__` as a stub method:

```
class foo:
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307014/python-str-versus-unicode) for more details.

Comment: after spending a lot of time going thru my code.. I did find a place where I was calling str to an object that does not have proper __str__ defined... thanks

Comment: @nitin so did you shadown str, or did you call str() on some object that doesn't support it? Please let us know what the object was.

Comment: I call str() on a object created by a zip() function. This does not support the built in __str__() method.

Comment: @nitin Don't `zip` functions just return an iterable (most likely a list or tuple)? They shouldn't have any problem with their `str` method.

Comment: @nitin Strange. IMHO that should fall back to `__repr__()` or one of `object`'s methods...

Comment: @nitin Revised my answer, thanks for accepting. Could we have a look at the code, please?? I don't think `zip` should be causing any problems...

Answer (score 5):

As mouad said, you've used the name `str` somewhere higher in the file. That shadows the existing built-in `str`, and causes the error. For example:

```
>>> mynum = 123
>>> print str(mynum)
123
>>> str = 'abc'
>>> print str(mynum)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: I cannot find any assignment to str in my function. Is this the only reason for this error>

Comment: I changed my code from str(vec) to vec.__str__()...  I still get the same err