# UnicodeDecodeError (once again) with format() but not with concatenation

Tags: python

I have a class chunk with text fields `title` and `text`. When I want to print them, I get (surprise, surprise!) `UnicodeDecodeError`. It gives me an error when I try to format an output string, but when I just concatenate text and title and return it, I get no error:

```
class Chunk:
  # init, fields, ...

  # this implementation will give me an error
  def __str__( self ):
    return u'{0} {1}'.format ( enc(self.text), enc(self.title) )

  # but this is OK - all is printed without error
  def __str__( self ):
    return enc(self.text) + enc(self.title)

def enc(x):
  return x.encode('utf-8','ignore') # tried many combinations of arguments...


c = Chunk()
c.text, c.title = ... # feed from external file
print c
```

Bum! Error!

```
return u'{0} {1}'.format ( enc(self.text), enc(self.title) )
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 2844: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I think I used all the possible combinations of `encode`/`decode`/`utf-8`/`ascii`/`replace`/`ignore`/...

(the python unicode issue is *really* irritating!)

Comment: put your input which rised an exception

Comment: have you read http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html and http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should [override `__unicode__`, not `__str__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307014/python-str-versus-unicode), when you return a unicode.
2. There is no need to call `.encode()`, since the input is already a unicode. Just write

   ```
   def __unicode__(self):
       return u"{0} {1}".format(self.text, self.title)
   ```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to avoid 2.x python's unicode problem is to set overall encoding to utf-8, or such a problems will be constantly arise in a sudden places:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Comment: This is a bad idea.  Sure, problems will arise, and you need to fix them - you have to know what data (characters) you work with and handle all the edge cases.  `setdefaultencoding` will just hide bugs.