# Custom string formatting for a list of objects

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have a list of objects. I am trying to output a meaningful representation of the objects in the list, that reveals some of the instance variables, using the [string formatting capability](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) built into recent versions of Python. I am using Python 3.3.0.

I have defined a `__str__` method in the class for the objects in my list. If I try to print an individual object, I get the representation returned by the `__str__` method. But if I try to print the whole list, I get the generic representation, as if I haven't defined the `__str__` method. Here is an example:

```
class CustomClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.instanceVar = 42

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} (instanceVar = {})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.instanceVar)

testObject = CustomClass()

print("{}".format(testObject))
# CustomClass (instanceVar = 42)

print("{}".format([testObject]))
# [<__main__.CustomClass object at 0x1006cbed0>]
```

How can I get the 2nd print statement to print something like `[CustomClass (instanceVar = 42)]`? Is it possible to do this just by passing the right format string to the `print` function or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: you could override `__repr__` too

Comment: @Joran Beasley and unutbu, both of you gave useful answers. Joran, I decided to accept your answer since you answered first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you would need to define its `__repr__` method I believe

```
class CustomClass:
     def __str__: 
         return "whatever"
     def __repr__:
         return str(self)
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I didn't think to try that.

Comment: When you implement __str__ sometimes you may also want to implement __unicode__ too - for differences check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307014/python-str-versus-unicode#1307210

Answer (score 3):

When printing a list, you get the `repr` of the objects in the list.
So to get the desired format, define the `__repr__` method.

If you do not define `__str__`, but define `__repr__`, then the `__repr__` will be used in place of `__str__` whenever Python tries to find the `str` of the object. So you don't have to define both if you don't want to.

```
class CustomClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.instanceVar = 42

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{} (instanceVar = {})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.instanceVar)
```