# __str__ returns UnicodeEncodeError, but otherwise works (u'\xa0')

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, unicode, encoding

I am experiencing the weirdest bug of my life.

I am fixing my [Hacker News API](https://github.com/karan/HackerNewsAPI) and this small piece of code is giving me headaches:

```
from hn import HN

hn = HN()


# print top stories from homepage
for story in hn.get_stories():
    print story.title
    print story
```

`Story` class a `__str__` method as follows:

```
def __str__(self):
    """
    Return string representation of a story
    """
    return self.title
```

(This is a little different from the code in the repo. I had to debug a lot here.)

Anyways, the output is this:

```
Turn O(n^2) reverse into O(n)
Turn O(n^2) reverse into O(n)
My run-in with unauthorised Litecoin mining on AWS
My run-in with unauthorised Litecoin mining on AWS
Amazon takes away access to purchased Christmas movie during Christmas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_test_bot.py", line 11, in <module>
    print story
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 60: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have no idea why this is failing. Both the `__str__` and the `print story` statements print a unicode. Then **why is the latter not working?**

Also, doing `print unicode(story)` works just fine (why??), but unfortunately I cannot use `unicode()` since it's not py3 compatible.

`title` is encoded as: `title.encode('cp850', errors='replace').decode('cp850')`

What the hell is happening here? How do I make sure that my API would work for any (meaning most) of the strings it can find and is both py2 and py3 compatible?

I have [downloaded the page](https://www.dropbox.com/s/di7qjlkrsho4yj7/hn.html) that is causing this error right now for offline debugging.

Comment: You should use the `str.encode` and `str.decode` methods. Either you work only with bytes array (py2 style) which I don't recommend, either you work only with unicode strings (using either `str.encode` or `print(u"Hello")`. By the way if you want to be compliant with both py2 and py3, use print as a function and not a keyword. Currently your problem is that you're trying to decode unicode chars with ascii codec. Which will never work. Ever. :P

Answer (score 2):

`__str__` returns a byte array, without any info about encoding, your console app is likely trying to encode whatever returned by `__str__` to ascii and failing at that. You can try and use `__unicode__` which returns characters. There's more info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307014/python-str-versus-unicode).

And yes, py3 only has `__str__` meta stuff, so you'll have to keep `__unicode__` for compatibility

Comment: This doesn't explain why `print story.title` apparently works but `print story` doesn't, since according to his code they should have the same result.

Comment: @BrenBam, not necessarily:  `print story.title` implicitly computes `str(story.title)` and prints the result of that.  But `print story` implicitly computes `str(story)` which is `story.__str__()` which returns `story.title`.  The builtin `str()` is *not* applied to `story.title` in the latter case, only in the former case.

Comment: Not really. This didn't really work. `return '[{0}]: "{1}" by {2}'.format(self.points, self.title, self.submitter)` in `__unicode__` still causes the error.

Comment: @KaranGoel, for your `__unicode__` method, you can use a `u''` literal if you only support Python 3 versions 3.3+. Otherwise you can decode the template before calling the `format` method. For a unified 2 & 3 codebase, consider using [Six](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#binary-and-text-data).

Comment: Adding a `u` in `__unicode__` did the trick in py2. Can you recommend some resources where I can learn more about py2 and py3 encodings and fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

This nasty kind of problems can often be explained when you try to save the output to the file instead of printing. Try:

```
for story in hn.get_stories():
    print type(story.title)
    print type(story)

    with open('content.txt', 'ab') as f:
        f.write(story.title)
        f.write('\n\n')
        f.write(story)
        f.write('\n-----------------------------------------------\n')
```

I expect this to be iterative approach to the solution. More facts is needed. You may be misleaded by something.