# Django interactiveshell returns model objects in object form and not as string

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

This code is from models.py in my App called article

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    likes = models.IntegerField()


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I've added 3 objects into the db like this

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> a = Article(title = "Test 1", body = "blah blah blah " ,pub_date=timezone.now(),likes=0)
>>> a.save()
>>> a.id
1
>>> a = Article(title = "Test 2", body = "blah blah blah " ,pub_date=timezone.now(),likes=0)
>>> a.save()
>>> a.id
2
>>> a = Article(title = "Test 3", body = "blah blah blah " ,pub_date=timezone.now(),likes=0)
>>> a.save()
>>> a.id
3
>>> Article.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Article: Article object>, <Article: Article object>, <Article: Article object>]>
```

whenever i called Article.objects.all() method it returns me the title in object form. 
From the documentation the **unicode** method must return me the actual title in the string form.

I'm new to Django and i've tried alot changing the **unicode** method but nothing seems to work. Thanks you in advance

here is the output I am getting

```
 from article.models import Article
>>> Article.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Article: Article object>, <Article: Article object>, <Article: Article object>]>
```

and the output i want

```
<QuerySet [<Article: Article Test 1>, <Article: Article Test 2>, <Article: Article Test 3>]>
```

Comment: Are you using python  2 or 3? If you are using python 3 use the __str__() method instead of __unicode__().

Comment: little more background information: [python-str-versus-unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307014/python-str-versus-unicode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change def `__unicode__(self):` to `def __str__(self):` as **unicode** version is used in Python2 and **str** in Python3