# django query not return me all fields

Tags: python, django

I am running a query and want to display all fields.

```
question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
```

In a model

```
class Question(models.Model):
    #id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

When I print data in a view it returns me only question text, I also want to display id and date.

template

```
{{ question }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
question = Question.objects.filter(pk=question_id)
```

**template**

```
{% for x in question %}
    {{x.pub_date}}
{% endfor %}
```

or your way
**template**
{{question.pub_date}}

Comment: If you have the `id`, it is much better & faster to use the `get` method instead of `filter`.

Comment: Yea but I think he is beginner. So both options are good for him :)

Answer (score 3):

You will have to specify the attribute in your template, like `{{ question.question_text }}`. Just using `{{ question }}` works because the `repr`, which defaults to `str` is defined as the `question_text` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `__str__` you should use `__unicode__`. See: [Python __str__ versus __unicode__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307014/python-str-versus-unicode)

Also, you should access in the template each field separately, but if you want to get just string with id, text and date, you can modify the method, so it returns all as a single string like:

`def __unicode__(self):
  return unicode(self.id)+", "+self.question_text+", "+unicode(self.pub_date)`