# Convert Python Exception to string fails with encoding error

Tags: python-2.7

I'm rather new at Python and am experiencing some issues printing the contents of an Exception:

```
# -*- coding: ISO-8859-1 -*-

    except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

yields "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\uf260' in position 52: ordinal not in range(128)"

I've tried reading https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type but the issue I'm encountering is that in order to decode and encode or use unicode(..,errors='ignore') I need a string and str(err) fails with the above error message.

This is in a Windows environ.  Thankful for any replies, even if it is "learn to search!" because in that case there was indeed a similar question that I missed while searching that's hopefully been answered : )

Edit. I've tried

```
print("Error {0}".format(str(err.args[0])).encode('utf-8', errors='ignore'))
```

which yields exactly the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\uf260' in
>   position 52: ordinal not in range(128)

Look in the error, character `\uf260` its not ascii, but something is trying to treat a non-ascii character as ascii. What?

Try this instead : `print err.__repr__()` .

**Explanation:**

`err` is an Exception object which has `__str__()` function implemented, so on printing an object `object.__str__()` method is called which essentially brings this error. You can verify by calling `print err.__str__()` to get similar error.

Also to check that Exception class module has `__str__()`, you can do `dir(Exception)`.

**Update:** [Check this link to understand how print picks up encoding.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596714/why-does-python-print-unicode-characters-when-the-default-encoding-is-ascii)

**References:**

[UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

[Python __str__ versus __unicode__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307014/python-str-versus-unicode)

[How to print a class or objects of class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-a-class-or-objects-of-class-using-print)

[Python: Converting from ISO-8859-1/latin1 to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539881/python-converting-from-iso-8859-1-latin1-to-utf-8)

[Why does Python print unicode characters when the default encoding is ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596714/why-does-python-print-unicode-characters-when-the-default-encoding-is-ascii)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, what you listed under Try this instead: gave the same error. In the end I converted the exception object to a string with repr() and then printed it. Am not sure where the weird "J" character came from but the error conveyed was nevertheless helpful.

Comment: Okay, sorry that I assumed that your string will be unicode ... the message you are printing is neither Unicode nor Ascii. So you need to use object.__repr__() method (aka repr(object)) or convert the message in this way: [convert from one format to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539881/python-converting-from-iso-8859-1-latin1-to-utf-8) ... I have updated the same in answer.